# Cloud VPN Connection Graph Anomaly

Tags: graph, graphics, cloud, metrics, google-cloud-vpn

I'm encountering an issue with the graph of my VPN connection. In the graph, there are what I call "gaps," which are moments when it stops displaying information. The only exception is Stackdriver, where the graph appears correctly.

Does anyone have any idea of what might be happening? Any suggestions or advice on how to fix this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAbVx.png)

Thanks in advance!